# Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.0)

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, chainlink, hardhat

**I was following Patrick Video
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oERTH9Bkw0&t=5700s" where I encounter this error at 2:31:20 and the code in that video is almost same as mine, still is not working**

```
//probably error is here below

        await transactionResponse.wait(1);
        log(`Now let's finish the mint...`);
        let finish_tx = await randomSVG.finishMInt(tokenId, { gasLimit: 2000000, gasPrice: 20000000000 });
        await finish_tx.wait(1);
        log(`You can view the tokenURI here ${await randomSVG.tokenURI(0)}`);

    }
};

module.exports.tags = ["all", "rsvg"];
```

Answer (score 0):

put all values you are passing inside quotes '' or "", this should work!